# Bootstrap modal with remote ASP.NET webforms url

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building up a website in ASP.NET Webforms and Bootstrap.

I have created a **webform with masterpage** page which contains a link to open up the Bootstrap modal with contents of another page ( **Test.aspx** ).

```
<a href="Test.aspx" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalTime">
    Launch demo modal
</a>
```

The Test.aspx page is also a **webform with masterpage** file because without the modal it has to have the same content ( header, footer, ... ) as all other pages when you surf to it.

But in the modal it also adds the content of the masterpage ( header, footer, ... ). Which is normal, I understand this.
But is their another way or component or something else that when you surf to Test.aspx you see all the contents and in the modal you only see some content? Displaying only content within a **Contentplaceholder**?

Or is this only possible in `MVC` because of the use of `views`? Maybe there is something simular in `webforms`?

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved in multiple ways. The two ways I would suggest is the following:

1) Move most logic out in an ASCX control. Then you can keep test.aspx, but also have a new one called Modaltest.aspx, and you can use that one for the modal window.

2) On the masterpage, you have a property called "IsAjax", that looks at the header. If the header is an AJAX call, you simply remove all its surroundings. We've done that at one of our legacy Web Forms project at work, which works OK.

Comment: The first solution is not good because if you then surf to ModalTest.aspx you don't have the header and so on, or it should be possible that the Modaltest.aspx is only available for the bootstrap modal is some kind of way. The second looks better but how do you implement this? I can't find the IsAjax property.

Comment: You need to make such a property, and then look at the request header.

Comment: Ok that works but now removing the surroundings, who do we accomplish that? So that only a sertain div and his contents is returned. I tried using the Response.Clear(); and then write new html code but that is not working.

Comment: Ok it works, I had to add the rule Response.End();. But now I have one more problem. I have an asp.net button control within my div **pnlModal** but now I get an error **Cannot get inner content of pnlModal because the contents are not literal.** when I try to stream the innerhtml of the pnlModal div.

Comment: I am trying to strip the surroundings. I have asked it in a new question: [Strip content out of the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23637247/strip-content-out-of-the-page-during-render?noredirect=1#comment36297260_23637247) . Can you tell me how you did it?